# How to make the right CV test?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I am going to indicate a really confused question for me in my project, I didn't learn machine learning before but I am hardworking on it, the question might be long and naive, and thanks for reading it.

**The ideal model:**
In my project, I need to record a patient's movement patterns and classify him to a relative muscle diseases, say the dieseases can be X,Y,and Z.

However, by considering about the painfulness of patients and other difficulties, to get the real data of them are impossible.
Therefore, to test if this kind of classification is feasible, I designed a CV process and also applied it.

**Simulation:**

The main thing I get confused is the individual difference, like the movement pattern of all patients with X-disease can be different. In my target model I don't what to distinguish them.

Therefore I asked five people to gather their data, let's say they are A,B,C,D and E, and control the physical condition to let them kind of sufferring from X, Y and Z muscle decieses(like I bind a rock on the knee etc).

Therefore I get 4*3 samples, AX,AY,AZ,BX,BY,BZ,CX,CY,CZ,DX,DY,DZ,EX,EY,EZ each of them represent a particular person forming a motion under a particular disease.

Now the problem is coming. I did several analysis about these data, but I don't know which one is right, or maybe everyone is fail.

1. I bin all of them with label X,Y,Z into randomly selected K-Foldered CV process, some particular model acheived really high classification rate, around 99%
2. I bin all of them with label X,Y,Z, except the data gathered from E(EX,EY,EZ), since I assumed E is a totally new patient need to be classified, into the learning process, and then predict all E's data without its label separately after, the classification rate is really low, not even 50%, and it might caused by the limited sample.

**Truth**
1. the window length of diagnose is 10s.
2. the sample length of each patient under each disease is 10 minitus. Thus, AX,AY,AZ,BX,BY ... EZ are all 10 minitus long.
3. The guys I got the sample A,B,C,D,E from are all have their identical movenment pattern in their normal life.

**Question**

**Which one is the valid CV process to represent my ideal model? (Assume we could get as large number samples from different people as possible)**, which cross-validation can finally represent the accuracy for my real target?

**When I only got five sample, Is the first K-Fold CV could objectively represent the accuracy of my real target? How objective it is?**

**Is there any better CV routine I can use?**

**Can I trust the 99% classification rate with the CV?** Especially when I use random forest.

**What happens?**  I guess it is because of we trained part of the E-sample in random selected K-Folder CV, that's why all rest of the E_sample can be correctly recognised in each CV iteration?

Really appreciated for any helps..

Comment: You have your simulated training set of 12 observations. Why not just use 12-fold cross validation? This would be assuming that each combination represents a different patient even though, for example, AX, AY, and AZ is from the same person.

Comment: Hi I tried that the result of random forest is 99 percent , is that kind of objective representation of my model? Which means if my sample is big enough , I could approach to this accuracy?